# HLD and LLD for elevator control software

Tags: oop, class-diagram

I have recently attended the amazon interview, and they asked to design an elevator control sofware. I have explained them algorithm wise, but they wanted to know the HLD and LLD. 
What should be the HLD and LLD for elevator control software?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to answer HLD and LLD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670692/how-to-answer-hld-and-lld)

Comment: I have checked it, but the answer is too brief. Can you please explain in detail giving an HLD and LLD for the elevator problem as an example to explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

The truth is that it is a myth in these days. HLD and LLD use to exist in early days of waterfall. In todays agile world one does harldy do big upfront design. Inspite of this, interviews ask this. So we need to learn in order to pass interview. HLD is the high level design of the system. It is more like a context diagram with boxes representing the different components. It may also outline the microservices if any or layers if any. For DB, it can show the data model. LLD is mainly the class diagram.